# List of List schema in spark Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am not able to create schema for below in java

```java
JavaRDD<Row> newRdd = dataset.javaRDD().map(new Function<Row, Row>() {
    @Override
    public Row call(Row r) throws Exception {
        String[] startLngLat = r.getString(7).split(",");
        String[] endLngLat = r.getString(8).split(",");
        
        List<List<Double>> latLng = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();
                
        List<Double> latlon = new ArrayList<Double>();
        latlon.add(Double.parseDouble(startLngLat[0]));
        latlon.add(Double.parseDouble(startLngLat[1]));
        latLng.add(latlon);
        
        List<Double> longlat = new ArrayList<Double>();
        longlat.add(Double.parseDouble(endLngLat[0]));
        longlat.add(Double.parseDouble(endLngLat[1]));
        latLng.add(longlat);                                
                       
        HashMap<String, String> mapObj = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mapObj.put("type", "LineString");
        mapObj.put("coordinates", latLng);
        
        Map<String, Object> geoMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        geoMap.put("geom", mapObj);
                
        Integer cf = r.getInt(9);
        Integer countryCode = r.getInt(10);
        Integer frc = r.getInt(11);             
        Row row = RowFactory.create(geoMap, cf, frc);               
        return row;
    }
});
Dataset<Row> dataset1 = sparkSession.createDataFrame(newRdd, schema);
```

Comment: @OneCricketeer Please remove _"1) You should use structured streaming if you want a schema, not RDD"_ from the comment above. It's incorrect. Schema is for Spark SQL (that Structured Streaming uses under the covers).

Comment: @OneCricketeer Not anymore 